# Van der Waals expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

My thermodynamics textbook says that 
$$pV_m = \frac{RT}{1-\frac{b}{V_m}}-\frac{a}{V_m}$$
where $b$ and $a$ are van der Waal's coefficients. Then it uses this expansions as follows:
$$(1-x)^{-1}= 1+x+x^2+x^3... \space\space\space\space\space\space|x|<1$$
$$\left(1-\frac{b}{V_m}\right)^{-1}=1+\frac{b}{V_m}+\left(\frac{b}{V_m}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{V_m}\right)^3...$$

What it doesn't explain is how it knows that $b<V_m$ which is a prerequisite for using this expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of this particular presentation of the Van der Waals equation, but I think $b$ represents the volume that a mole of gas excludes by virtue of the molecules not being point particles. So in a sence $b < V_m$ is a statement that the gas is not very dense. In other words, when $b$ is of order $V_m$, you've got yourself a liquid or critical point goop.

Comment: In the book it says $b$ is a representation of the repulsive interactions between molecules and has dimensions (Volume/Mole)

Comment: I was just refreshing my memory using [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation), but I think the idea is that since particles can't get too close to eachother due to intermolecular forces, that is volume that is unavailable to the kinetic model of the gas.